# Number of Boolean algebra subintervals in weak order of $S_n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, symmetric-groups, coxeter-groups, algebraic-combinatorics

I'm wondering if anybody has an easy way to compute the number of subintervals in weak order of $S_n$ (considered as a Coxeter group of type $A_{n-1}$) that are isomorphic to Boolean algebras. I know $[u,v]$ is such a subinterval if and only if $u\leq v$ and $vu^{-1}$ is a product of adjacent transpositions that pairwise commute with each other. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Exercise 3.185(h) in my book *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 1, second ed. If $f(n,i)$ denotes the number of intervals in the weak order of $S_n$ that are isomorphic to boolean algebras of rank $i$, then
  $$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{i\geq 0}f(n,i)q^i\frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{1}{1-x-\frac 
     12 qx^2}. $$
Putting $q=1$ shows that the total number $f(n)$ of boolean intervals
satisfies
  $$ f(n+1)=(n+1)f(n)+{n+1\choose 2}f(n-1). $$
 Unfortunately no solution is included.

Comment: Thanks. I've expressed the number of commutation classes of reduced words for the longest element as a determinant, and I think I could organize this into a bound with Hsdamard's inequality. I'm thinking the bound will probably be trivial, but we'll see.

Comment: @MattSamuel: What is the determinant? This could be interesting for its own sake if it isn't too big or complicated.

Comment: The element $C$ of the incidence algebra such that $C(u,v)$ is the number of commutation classes of $vu^{-1}$ is the inverse of a very simple element of the incidence algebra, namely $C^{-1}(u,v)=0$ unless $[u,v]$ is a Boolean algebra, in which case $C^{-1}(u,v)=(-1)^{\ell(u,v)}$.

Comment: For further information about this problem, see https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.14734